# how can I display errors in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

i don't seem to be able to show errors in codeigniter.
I've changed the Index.php file to development and also added error reporting and display errors like this

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');    
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
case 'development':
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set(‘display_errors’,1);
break;
//....
```

with this setup I would expect to get errors when, for example, i try to load a model which doesn't exist, or there is a typo in my code or any other error. but all i get is a blank page...

Comment: What happens if you add `die('test');` into the development case?

Comment: i see a blank page with 'test' written on it

Comment: I've noticed that the QUOTATION MARKS surrounding display_errors in the ini_set instruction were smart quotation marks. I've changed them to double quotes (") and it now seems to work. Weird!!

Comment: Always use the `'` quotation marks when you're not parsing the string though. Saves you a very small amount of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you enable error reporting in php.ini?